# Sum of table column returns incorrect value

Tags: javascript, ajax

Evening folks, first of all I am not too familiar with either JavaScript or AJAX I - I have some basic knowledge. With this basic knowledge and the use of StackOverflow and Copilot I have the following code. I have a table in HTML with a total column which I would like to sum at the bottom.

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td style="vertical-align: center;"><strong>Total</strong></td>
    <td id="total">£0.00</td>
</tr>
```

I am using HTMX to allow users to enter values so the contents of the table are dynamic

```
$("Table").change(function() {
    $("#total").html(sumColumn(4));
});

function sumColumn(index) {
    var total = 0;
    $("td:nth-child(" + index + ")").each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).text().replace(/\u00A3/g, ''), 10) || 0;
});  
return "£" + total;
}
```

This code does work but only up to the value of 1000, e.g. If I enter 10 * 5 it will show 50 however if I enter 1000 * 20 instead of showing 20,000 it will show 20? I am at a bit of a loss as to why this would happen looking at the code, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide an example that we can run so we can experience your issue? While editing the question, look for the `<>` icon in the editor to create a snippet.

Comment: parseInt takes numbers until the first character that is not numeric. parseInt(20,000) === 20. Try to remove the comma first.

Comment: Not sure why you are explicitly stating it's base 10 - that is the default. And anways, you could simplify this a bit with something like `total += +$(this).text().replace(/\D/g,'');`